# How can you render a react component using dynamic name?

Tags: reactjs

Here's what I've tried and all it does is insert html with the theme value as the tag. It doesn't create an actual React Component.

!!! Let's assume the theme name is '**rounded**'

```
renderTemplate(){
    const store = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('store'));
    const template = this.state.product.template;
    const Theme = `${template.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${template.slice(1)}`;
    return <Theme store={this.props.store} product={this.state.product} />;
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>
            { _.isEmpty(this.state.product) ?
                'LOADING'
                :
                this.renderTemplate()
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Also, I read in another question that someone mentioned something about it can't be wrapped in an html element so I also tried this unsuccessfully:

```
render(){
    return (
        _.isEmpty(this.state.product) ?
            <div>LOADING</div>
            :
            this.renderTemplate()
    )
}
```

Both cases just render html elements like (from console inspector):

```
<div class="row">
    <rounded store="XXXXX" product="XXXXX"></rounded>
    <rounded store="XXXXX" product="XXXXX"></rounded>
    <rounded store="XXXXX" product="XXXXX"></rounded>
</div>
```

In React Inspector:

```
<div class="row">
    <Rounded store="XXXXX" product="XXXXX"></Rounded>
    <Rounded store="XXXXX" product="XXXXX"></Rounded>
    <Rounded store="XXXXX" product="XXXXX"></Rounded>
</div>
```

And if it helps the React Console shows each of the divs children as:

```
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
    Empty object
```

EDIT !!!!

```
Import Rounded from ‘./Themes/Rounded’;
```

In case it is missed here... what I need to accomplish is rendering an actual react component named `<Rounded />`

EDIT 2 !!!!

Here is the complete code (minus anything irrelevant):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// IMPORT THEMES
import {
    Rounded,
    Square,
    [Other themes here]
} from './Themes';

class MyClass extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            product: {}
        };
    }

    renderTemplate(){
        const template = this.state.product.template;
        const Theme = `${template.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${template.slice(1)}`;
        return <Theme product={this.state.product} />;
    }

    render(){
        return (
            _.isEmpty(this.state.product) ?
                <div>LOADING</div>
                :
                this.renderTemplate()
        )
    }
}

export default MyClass;
```

Comment: Did you mean to see `react-rounded` as the tag name?

Comment: No, I need to render a component ‘Rounded’ and I edited the question to reflect this more clearly I hope.

Comment: React inspector actually shows `<Rounded />` components so what's your issue ?

Comment: @Tomas this code `this.state.product.template.charAt(0).toUpperCase()` to my mind will return teh only button. is it okay?)

Comment: have you tried `Theme = template.charAt(0).toUpperCase + template.slice(1)`?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to update my code here. That's exactly what I've got and it does not work as a React Component.

Comment: Theme is a String. You can't just create a String (`${template.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${template.slice(1)}`) and expect it to render. React components must be a function or a class.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it!

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// IMPORT THEMES
import * as Themes from './Themes';

class MyClass extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            product: {}
        };
    }

    renderTemplate(){
        const template = this.state.product.template;
        const Theme = Themes[template.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + template.slice(1)];
        return <Theme product={this.state.product} />;
    }

    render(){
        return (
            _.isEmpty(this.state.product) ?
                <div>LOADING</div>
                :
                this.renderTemplate()
        )
    }
}

export default MyClass;
```

Notice the `import * as` which automatically sticks all classes in an array for you. An array of functions I should mention. So now `Themes[]` is a direct reference to a function and not just a string.